# What's the meaning "jumped the joint"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What's the meaning "jumped the joint"?

Full sentence:

> Pepe: My bro jumped the joint, deserved a hero's welcome...

It's from *Cyberpunk2077* game.

Does it mean that his brother just leaves him? Or something more?

Comment: [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jump%20the%20joint) is useful for slang, but I'm not confident that there is enough context in the question to say this is the answer. What are the circumstances where that sentence is used? What occasion does it refer to?

Comment: It most likely means "broke out of prison" https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/joint#English

Comment: Ok. thanks you are right. Now I understood all the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Jumped the joint" usually means that you are doing it quickly, like "I am zooming out of here."
That is what I have been told it means.

In that context it most likely means just that like he had a heroic entrance or something.

I hope this is helpful advice and helps you out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).